# How do I aggregate based on a struct field in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My current schema after some aggregation steps looks like this:

| Id | Name | Car | Struct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alex | Porsche | {sub-id: "car1", country: "US"}, {sub-id: "car1", country: "Mexico"}, {sub-id: "car-1", country: Canada}, {sub-id: "car-2", country: "Mexico"} |
| 2 | Alex | Toyota | {sub-id: "car-2", country: "Germany"}, {sub-id: "car-3", country: "Brazil"}, {sub-id: "car-2", country: "US"} |
| 3 | Ben | BMW | {sub-id: "car-2", country: "Germany"}, {sub-id: "car-3", country: "Brazil"}, {sub-id: "car-2", country: "US"} |

I want to aggregate across sub-id so that it would look like:

| Id | Name | Car | Struct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alex | Porsche | {sub-id: "car1", country: "US", other-country: [Mexico, Canada]}, {sub-id: "car1", country: "Mexico"}, {sub-id: "car-1", country: Canada}, {sub-id: "car-2", country: "Mexico"} |
| 2 | Alex | Toyota | {sub-id: "car-2", country: "Germany"}, {sub-id: "car-3", country: "Brazil"}, {sub-id: "car-2", country: "US", other-country: ["Germany", "Brazil"]} |
| 3 | Ben | BMW | {sub-id: "car-2", country: "Germany"}, {sub-id: "car-3", country: "Brazil"}, {sub-id: "car-2", country: "US", other-country: ["Germany", "Brazil"]} |

On every row:

1. aggregate across unique sub-ids like "car1"
2. only if the country is US, add a list of other countries

I have been on this for 3 days. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share how your input file looks like ? Looks like you are aggregating on Name but just wanted to understand input.

Comment: The aggregation is across (id, name, car)

Comment: please share your expected output ?

Comment: @s.polam - the expected output is in the description!